# Primitive binary necklaces

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, necklace-and-bracelets, lyndon-words

The problem/solution of counting the number of (primitive) necklaces (Lyndon words) is very well known.

But what about results giving sufficient conditions for a given necklace be primitive? For example, in the binary case, a necklace of length $N$ (00..00100..01) will be primitive whenever the number $M$ of zeros between the two 1's is such that $\gcd(N,M)=1$.

Any idea/references for additional results of this type?

Comment: Are cyclically permuted necklaces considered the same necklace?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber
binary necklace is an equivalence class of binary strings under rotation. If the strings have length n, then the size of the equivalence class is at most n (it's actually a divisor of n).
We call the necklace primitive if size of the equivalence class is is large as possible; that is, the size is n.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of primitive strings of length $n$, call it $p_n$, is easy to get. The total number of length $n$ strings made of $s$ symbols is just $s^n$. All strings are made of repeats of some primitive string (in case it is primitive, it is one repeat). So:
$$
s^n = \sum_{d \mid n} p_d
$$
and Möbius inversion gives:
$$
p_n = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(n/d) s^d
$$
Now each primitive necklace (i.e., cycle) can be cut at $n$ places to get different primitive strings, so the number of primitive necklaces is just:
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(n/d) s^d
$$

Comment: To @vonbrand, I was able to finish a computation that you started, it is at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761658).

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add some linked material from the OEIS to this thread in order to facilitate further exploration of this problem. (The amount of material at the OEIS indicates that this problem has interested many combinatorics enthusiasts.) We show how to count primitive necklaces of at most $N$ colors. Recall that the Polya Enumeration Theorem tells us that the total number of necklaces (rotational symmetry only) on at most $N$ colors is given by the substituted cycle index of the cyclic group
$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}$$
which is, supposing there are $N$ colors,
$$q_n = Z(C_n)(c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_N)_{c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_N=1}
\\= \left.
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) (c_1^d+c_2^d+\cdots+c_N^d)^{n/d}
\right|_{c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_N=1}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) N^{n/d}.$$
Let the number of primitive necklaces be $p_n$, then it is perfectly straightforward to show that
$$\sum_{d|n} p_d = q_n.$$
Apply Moebius inversion to this to obtain
$$p_n = \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(n/d)}{d}
\left(\sum_{f|d} \varphi(f) N^{d/f}\right).$$

Here is the Maple code to compute this function.

```
with(numtheory);

p := proc(n, N)
local d, f, res;
    res := 0;
    for d in numtheory:-divisors(n) do for f in numtheory:-divisors(d) do
            res := res + numtheory:-mobius(n/d)*numtheory:-phi(f)*N^(d/f)/d
        end do
    end do;
    res
end proc
```

This gives for two colors ($N=2$) the sequence
$$2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 30, 56, 99, 186, 335, 630, 1161, 2182,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A001037](https://oeis.org/A001037).

For three colors ($N=3$) we get the sequence
$$3, 3, 8, 18, 48, 116, 312, 810, 2184, 5880, 16104, 44220, 122640, 341484, 956576,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A027376](https://oeis.org/A027376).

Finally for four colors ($N=4$) we get the sequence
$$4, 6, 20, 60, 204, 670, 2340, 8160, 29120, 104754, 381300, 1397740, 5162220,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A027377](https://oeis.org/A027377).

**Addendum.** According to the OEIS, the above formula for $p_n$ simplifies to
$$p_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) N^{n/d}.$$

**The simplification of the above goes like this.**

Start with
$$p_n = \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(n/d)}{d} 
\left(\sum_{f|d} \varphi(f) N^{d/f}\right).$$

Re-index setting $d/f=q$ so that $d=fq$ to obtain
$$p_n = \sum_{q|n} N^q
\sum_{f|n/q} \frac{\mu(n/f/q)}{fq} \varphi(f).$$

This is
$$p_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{q|n} N^q
\sum_{f|n/q} \frac{\mu(n/f/q)}{fq/n} \varphi(f).$$
Putting $m= n/q$ the inner sum becomes
$$\sum_{f|m} \mu(m/f) \times m/f \times \varphi(f).$$

This is a  convolution of multiplicative functions so  we only need to
verify it for prime powers $m = p^v.$ This gives two terms namely for
$f = p^v$ and $f = p^{v-1}$, which for $v\ge 2$ contribute
$$1 \times 1 \times \varphi(p^v)
- 1 \times p \times \varphi(p^{v-1})
= p^v - p^{v-1} - p (p^{v-1} - p^{v-2}) = 0.$$
For $v=1$ we get
$$1 \times 1 \times \varphi(p)
- 1 \times p \times \varphi(1)
= p-1 - p = -1.$$
Finally for $m=1$ we get $1.$
This shows that (using the convolution being multiplicative)
$$\sum_{f|m} \mu(m/f) \times m/f \times \varphi(f) = \mu(m)$$
and we finally have
$$p_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{q|n} N^q \mu(n/q).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here  is another  answer  that  presents an  additional  twist to  the
problem  of   counting  primitive  necklaces,  namely   **Power  Group
Enumeration** (as presented by Harary  and Palmer and Fripertinger, in
a different publication), with the group acting on the slots where the
$N$ colors are placed being the cyclic group $C_n$ on $n$ elements and
the  group acting  on  the colors  being the  symmetric  group on  $N$
elements $S_N$.

This treats  the problem of counting primitive  necklaces where colors
may  be  swapped  without  the resulting  necklaces  being  considered
different.

As in the other answer we  have the relation $$\sum_{d|n} p_d = q_n,$$
but now $q_n$  is computed by **Power Group  Enumeration**. No formula
will be given but we will explain how to compute $q_n$ and present the
relevant Maple code. The  desired value for *primitive* necklaces then
follows by $$p_n = \sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d) q_d.$$

We can compute the number  $q_n$ of configurations by Burnside's lemma
which says to average the number  of assignments fixed by the elements
of the power group, which has $N!\times |C_n|$ elements and $|C_n|=n$.
But this  number is easy  to compute.   Suppose we have  a permutation
$\alpha$ from $C_n$ and a permutation  $\beta$ from $S_N.$ If we place
the appropriate number of complete, directed and consecutive copies of
a cycle from $\beta$ on a  cycle from $\alpha$ then this assignment is
fixed  under the  power group  action, and  this is  possible iff  the
length of the cycle from $\beta$  divides the length of the cycle from
$\alpha$ and there are as many assignments as the length of $\beta.$

Now the  Burnside computation  is best  done with a  CAS, here  is the
Maple code.

```
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
        local terml, d, cf, v;

        terml := [];

        cf := varp;
        for v in indets(varp) do
            d := degree(varp, v);
            terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
            cf := cf/v^d;
        od;

        [cf, terml];
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
        1/n*add(phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d), d in divisors(n));
end;

q :=
proc(n, N)
    option remember;
    local idx_colors, res, a, b,
    flat_a, flat_b, cyc_a, cyc_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n=1 then
       idx_colors := [a[1]]
    else
       idx_colors := pet_cycleind_symm(N);
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for a in pet_cycleind_cyclic(n) do
        flat_a := pet_flatten_term(a);

        for b in idx_colors do
            flat_b := pet_flatten_term(b);

            p := 1;
            for cyc_a in flat_a[2] do
                len_a := op(1, cyc_a);
                q := 0;

                for cyc_b in flat_b[2] do
                    len_b := op(1, cyc_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q;
            od;

            res := res + p*flat_a[1]*flat_b[1];
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

p := (n, N) -> add(mobius(n/d)*q(d,N), d in divisors(n));
```

This gives for two colors ($N=2$) the sequence
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 16, 28, 51, 93, 170,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A000048](https://oeis.org/A000048).

For three colors ($N=3$) we get the sequence
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 22, 52, 140, 366, 992, 2684, 7404,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A002075](https://oeis.org/A002075).

Finally for four colors ($N=4$) we get the sequence
$$1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 35, 102, 360, 1232, 4427, 15934, 58465,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A056300](https://oeis.org/A056300).

**Additional linkage.** For $N=5$ we find a the sequence
$$1, 1, 2, 5, 11, 38, 122, 496, 2005, 8707, 38364, 173562,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A056301](https://oeis.org/A056301).

For $N=6$ we finde the sequence
$$1, 1, 2, 5, 11, 39, 125, 532, 2301, 11010, 54681, 284023,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A056302](https://oeis.org/A056302).

For $N=7$ we find the sequence
$$1, 1, 2, 5, 11, 39, 126, 536, 2353, 11606, 60498, 336399,\ldots$$
which is not yet in the OEIS.

**Addendum Sat Apr 21 2018.** The algorithm just presented admits of a
considerable improvement, namely that there  is no need to flatten the
permutations because we  can compute the contribution  from the cycles
of a pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ by  multiplying the number of coverings of
a cycle  type from $\alpha$  by the number  of instances of  the cycle
type from  $\beta$, raising the result  to the power of  the number of
instances of the  cycle type from $\alpha.$

This yields the following Maple code.

```
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
    1/n*add(phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d), d in divisors(n));
end;

q := proc(n, N)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_colors, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n = 1 then
        idx_slots := [a[1]];
    else
        idx_slots := pet_cycleind_cyclic(n);
    fi;

    if N = 1 then
        idx_colors := [a[1]];
    else
        idx_colors := pet_cycleind_symm(N);
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_slots do
        for term_b in idx_colors do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

p := (n, N) -> add(mobius(n/d)*q(d,N), d in divisors(n));
```