# Is there a nice characterization of these classes of functions on a set of $n$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I am looking at the set of all functions from $[n] \to [n]$, where $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Now, I consider two functions equivalent, if they are conjugates by some permutation, that is, they are the same upto renaming of the elements.

For example, if $n=3$, I consider $1\mapsto 1,2\mapsto3,3\mapsto3$ to be equivalent to $1\mapsto 1,2\mapsto2,3\mapsto1$. Is there a "nice" set of representatives, or a nice characterization of the equivalence classes? If there is no "perfect" characterization, is there a set of representatives with fairly few repetitions of the same class?

As an analogue, if we were to consider only permutations, instead of all functions, each (unordered) partition of $[n]$ characterizes a class via the cycle decomposition.

**Some progress:** Every class has some function $f$ that satisfies $f(x) \leq x+1$ for each $x$.

If we consider each function as a graph on $n$ nodes, then each class almost corresponds to graphs of the following form upto isomorphism:

A number of disjoint cycles, with some trees attached some of the nodes of the cycles.

Comment: This might be a good application for Burnside's lemma.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that we have $n$ slots and  we can place any one of $n$ values
in them, with  the symmetric group acting on the  slots and the values
simultaneously. We will solve this problem using Burnside.

What we  have here is a  special and unique  variant of **Simultaneous
Power  Group Enumeration**  (as  presented by  Harary  and Palmer  and
Fripertinger, in a differet publication), with the group acting on the
$n$ slots where the $n$ values are placed being the symmetric group on
$n$ elements  $S_n$ which  acts on the  values themselves at  the same
time.

We can compute the number $q_n$ of functions by Burnside's lemma which
says to average the number of assignments fixed by the elements of the
group acting  on the slots and  values, which has  $n!$ elements.  But
this number is easy to compute.

Suppose  we have a  permutation $\beta$  from $S_n.$  If we  place the
appropriate number  of complete, directed and consecutive  copies of a
cycle from $\beta$  on another cycle from $\beta$  (possibly the same)
then  this assignment is  fixed under  the group  action, and  this is
possible iff  the length of the  first cycle from  $\beta$ divides the
length of second cycle from  $\beta$ and there are as many assignments
as the length of the first cycle from $\beta.$

This uses the recurrence by Lovasz  for the cycle  index $Z(S_n)$, 
which is
$$Z(S_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n a_l Z(S_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

Actually  doing  the  computation  we  obtain  for  the  number  of
functions the following sequence:
$$1, 3, 7, 19, 47, 130, 343, 951, 2615, 7318, \ldots $$
which directs us to [OEIS A001372](https://oeis.org/A001372).

This link includes an important  observation, namely that what we have
here is the following unlabelled species:
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{MSET}(\textsc{CYC}(\mathcal{T}))
\quad\text{where}\quad
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{MSET}(\mathcal{T}).$$

The Maple code to compute these is as follows.

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
        local terml, d, cf, v;

        terml := [];

        cf := varp;
        for v in indets(varp) do
            d := degree(varp, v);
            terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
            cf := cf/v^d;
        od;

        [cf, terml];
end;

q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local idx_colors, res, b,
    flat, cyc_a, cyc_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n=1 then
       idx_colors := [a[1]]
    else
       idx_colors := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for b in idx_colors do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(b);

        p := 1;

        for cyc_a in flat[2] do
            len_a := op(1, cyc_a);

            q := 0;
            for cyc_b in flat[2] do
                len_b := op(1, cyc_b);

                if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                    q := q + len_b;
                fi;

            od;

            p := p*q;
        od;

        res := res + p*flat[1];
    od;

    res;
end;
```

**Addendum Sat  Apr 21 2018.**  While the algorithm we  presented here
will  produce  the   correct  result,  it  nonetheless   admits  of  a
considerable improvement, namely that there  is no need to flatten the
permutation because we can compute the contribution from a pair of two
cycle  types of  the permutation  $\beta$  with the  first type  being
covered by  the second by multiplying  the number of coverings  of the
first by the number of instances  of the second, raising the result to
the power  of the number of  instances of the first.   This yields the
following code.

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

q :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx_colors, res, term_a,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n = 1 then
        idx_colors := [a[1]];
    else
        idx_colors := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_colors do
        p := 1;

        for v_a in indets(term_a) do
            len_a := op(1, v_a);
            inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

            q := 0;

            for v_b in indets(term_a) do
                len_b := op(1, v_b);
                inst_b := degree(term_a, v_b);

                if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                    q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                fi;
            od;

            p := p*q^inst_a;
        od;

        res := res + lcoeff(term_a)*p;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325957/) also
does   **Power   Group  Enumeration**,   as   does   this  [MSE   link
II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/).

Answer (score 1):

My attempt to make this a group theory problem:

I'm going to start with a half-way version: I'll say that two functions are equivalent if you can switch around the entries on the right side of the $\mapsto$ to get from one function to the other.

I'm going to say that any function $f:[n]\rightarrow[n]$ can be uniquely denoted as a list of the form $x=\{f(1),f(2),...,f(n)\}$, and I will call the collection of these lists $X$.  Now, the action action that I may apply to this group is any permutation of these elements, that is, $G=S_n$, and for each permutation $g\in G,x\in X$: $g\cdot x=\{f(g(1)),f(g(2)),...,f(g(n))\}$.  What we want is the number of distinct orbits (i.e. the number of equivalence classes) of $X$ as acted upon by $G$.  Note, by the way, that $X$ is a set of size $n^n$.

Burnside's lemma tells us that this number corresponds to

$$
|X/G|=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|X^g|
$$
Where $|X^g|$ is the number of elements of $X$ fixed by a given permutation. I think the best way to explain what I mean here is by example.  Let's consider what this means for $n=3$:

In the case of $n=3$, you could permute elements by doing nothing, which you can do in one way, switch two elements, which you can do in three ways, and shift every element right or left wrapping around, which you can do in one way.  That is, there are $3!=6=|G|$ possible permutations.  Now we look at which elements of $X$ are fixed by which elements of $G$:

*do nothing*: if $g$ does nothing, then $|X^g|=3^3=27$

*switch two*: if $g$ switch two elements, then $|X^g|$ is the set of all elements for which those two elements are the same.  So, $|X^g|=3^2=9$

*shift right or left*: if $g$ shifts the elements, then $|X^g|$ contains only the constant functions.  So, $|X^g|=3$

This tells us that our number of orbits is
$$
\frac16(1\times27+3\times9+2\times3)=10
$$
That is, by this method of counting, there are 10 functions from $[3]$ to $[3]$.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: +1 for the ideas, but note that you're looking at a somewhat different problem. For the equivalence noted in the question, there are $7$ classes for $n=3$. And the action I would look at is $g.f = g^{-1}fg$.

Comment: Ah, good, you've seen this stuff before.  I modified your problem because I wasn't sure how to get the right action, and I thought there might be a way to get from this halfway solution to what you're looking for.  I'll update that if I can come up with anything to add to make this more comprehensive.