# Number of ordered, unlabeled binary rooted trees with n nodes and k leafs

Tags: generating-functions, trees, combinatorial-species

I want to find the number of ordered, unlabeled binary rooted trees with $n$ nodes and $k$ leafs as an exercise.

To be more precise. I am interested in objects like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybElK.png) ([(c) 2015 M. Fulmek, *PS Kombinatorik*](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~mfulmek/scripts/KOMBI/uebungen.pdf)) where the line below $n=4$ reads “… and the 7 trees above vertically filpped”

Assigning the weight $w(x)W = z^n y^k$ to every rooted tree $W$ with $n$ nodes and $k$ leafs. The generating function in two indeterminates should start like this

$$ T(z, y) = \sum_W w(x)W = zy + z^2 2y + z^3\left(y^2 + 4y\right) + z^4\left(6y^2 + 8y\right) + \ldots $$

I know that the number of ordered, unlabeled binary rooted trees with $n$ nodes is

$$ \bar T (z) = T(z, 1) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n + 1} {2n \choose n} z^n. $$

However, I do not know how to proceed from here. How can I express the number of leafs in terms of species?

I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761658/number-of-all-labeled-unordered-rooted-trees-with-n-vertices-and-k-leaves) question.
However, we did not cover Lagrange inversion in class. So I believe there should be a solution without applying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this question we run into the problem of determining exactly what
the notation is supposed to mean  and which family of trees from among
the  many possibilities  is being  referenced.  Note  that  the quoted
series with leaves not marked includes a tree of size zero, which does
not match the  quoted expansion. If we do use  the quoted expansion as
the problem definition it appears the species here is

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z}\mathcal{Y}
+ \mathcal{Z}\mathcal{T}
+ \mathcal{Z}\mathcal{T}
+ \mathcal{Z}\mathcal{T}^2.$$

We chose this  interpretation because the OP says  that there are four
trees  on three  nodes  with one  leaf,  which upon  making a  diagram
reveals  itself to  be  four paths  ending  in a  node  marked with  a
leaf. For this  to happen we must permit internal  nodes that have one
rather than two  children, so these trees are not  full.  This is what
the species  equation does: we have the  base case of a  leaf node, an
internal node with  a left child, an internal node  with a right child
or an internal node having two children.

This  yields  the  following  equation for  the  bivariate  generating
function:

$$T(z,y) = yz + 2zT(z,y) + zT(z,y)^2.$$

Now clearly  Lagrange or similar is  the preferred way  to treat this,
but according  to OP it  may not be  used.  Solving this  equation and
choosing the branch that yields Catalan numbers we obtain

$$T(z, y) = \frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z(1-z+yz)}}{2z}.$$

Extracting coefficients we have with  $n\ge 1$ (no empty trees in this
species):

$$[z^n] T(z, y) = [z^n] \frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z(1-z+yz)}}{2z}
\\ = [z^{n+1}] \frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z(1-z+yz)}}{2}
\\ = - [z^{n+1}] \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4z(1-z+yz)}.$$

Observe that

$$\sqrt{1-4w} = 1 + \sum_{q\ge 1} {1/2\choose q} 4^q  (-1)^q w^q$$

and

$$2^{2q} (-1)^q {1/2\choose q} 
= \frac{2^{2q}}{q!} (-1)^q \prod_{p=0}^{q-1} (1/2-p)
= \frac{2^{q}}{q!} \prod_{p=0}^{q-1} (2p-1)
\\ = - \frac{2^{q}}{q!} \prod_{p=1}^{q-1} (2p-1)
= - \frac{2^{q}}{q!} \frac{(2q-2)!}{2^{q-1}\times (q-1)!}
= - \frac{2}{q} {2q-2\choose q-1}.$$

Returning to the coefficient extraction we have

$$[z^{n+1}] \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{q} {2q-2\choose q-1} 
z^q (1-z+yz)^q
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{q} {2q-2\choose q-1} 
[z^{n+1}] z^q (1-z+yz)^q
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{q} {2q-2\choose q-1} 
[z^{n+1-q}](1-z(1-y))^q
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{q} {2q-2\choose q-1} 
{q\choose n+1-q} (-1)^{n+1-q} (1-y)^{n+1-q}.$$

We thus have for the statistic  of $n$ nodes and $k$ leaves the closed
form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^{n+1-k} \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^q}{q} {2q-2\choose q-1} 
{q\choose n+1-q} {n+1-q\choose k}.}$$

We continue by observing that

$$\frac{1}{q} {2q-2\choose q-1} {q\choose n+1-q} {n+1-q\choose k}
\\ = \frac{(2q-2)!}{(q-1)!\times (2q-n-1)! 
\times k! \times (n+1-q-k)!}
\\ = {n-k\choose q-1}
\frac{(2q-2)!}{(n-k)! \times (2q-n-1)! 
\times k!}
\\ = {n-k\choose q-1} {n\choose k} \frac{1}{2q-1}
{2q-1\choose n}.$$

We get for the sum

$$(-1)^{n+1-k} {n\choose k} \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^q}{2q-1}
{n-k\choose q-1} {2q-1\choose n}
\\ = (-1)^{n+1-k} {n\choose k} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{q+1}}{2q+1}
{n-k\choose q} {2q+1\choose n}$$

or (recall that $n\ge 1$)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n} (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n} (-1)^q
{n-k\choose q} {2q\choose n-1}.}$$

Working on the inner term we find

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n} (-1)^q
{n-k\choose q} [w^{n-1}] (1+w)^{2q}
\\ = [w^{n-1}] \sum_{q=0}^{n} (-1)^q
{n-k\choose q} (1+w)^{2q}
\\ = [w^{n-1}] (1-(1+w)^2)^{n-k}
= (-1)^{n-k} [w^{n-1}] w^{n-k} (2+w)^{n-k}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [w^{k-1}] (2+w)^{n-k}
= (-1)^{n-k} {n-k\choose k-1} 2^{n+1-2k}.$$

We thus obtain for the sum

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{2^{n+1-2k}}{n} {n\choose k} {n-k\choose k-1}.}$$

This may be re-written one last time if desired:

$$2^{n+1-2k} \frac{(n-1)!}{k!\times (k-1)! \times (n+1-2k)!}
\\ = \frac{2^{n+1-2k}}{k} {2k-2\choose k-1} {n-1\choose 2k-2}$$

and we have in terms of Catalan numbers

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n-1\choose 2k-2} C_{k-1} 2^{n+1-2k}.}$$

Surprising to see  that we got this far  without complex variables. We
did consult [OEIS  A091894](https://oeis.org/A091894), which proved to
be a valuable resource.

**Post Scriptum.** Does it sum to Catalan numbers? Start with

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k\ge 1} {n\choose k} {n-k\choose k-1} 2^{-2k}
= \frac{2^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k\ge 1} {n\choose k} 2^{-2k}
[w^{k-1}] (1+w)^{n-k}
\\ = \frac{2^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k\ge 1} {n\choose k} 
[w^0] \frac{(1+w)^n}{2^{2k} (1+w)^k w^{k-1}}
\\ = [w^0] w(1+w)^n \frac{2^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k\ge 1} {n\choose k} 
\frac{1}{2^{2k} (1+w)^k w^{k}}.$$

For $k=0$ we  get $[w^0] w(1+w)^n 2^{n+1}/n = 0$ and  we may lower the
index to include zero, obtaining

$$[w^0] w(1+w)^n  \frac{2^{n+1}}{n}
\left(1+\frac{1}{4w(1+w)}\right)^n
\\ = [w^0] w(1+w)^n  \frac{2^{n+1}}{n} 
\frac{(1+2w)^{2n}}{2^{2n} w^n (1+w)^n}
\\ = [w^0] \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{n} 
\frac{(1+2w)^{2n}}{2^{n-1}}
= [w^{n-1}]\frac{1}{n} 
\frac{(1+2w)^{2n}}{2^{n-1}}
= \frac{1}{n} {2n\choose n-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n},$$

and indeed it does.

Consulting with **combstruct** on these we have the following program.

```
with(combstruct);

GFENUM :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local trees, leaves;

    trees := { T=Union(Prod(Z, Y),
                       Prod(Z, T), Prod(Z, T),
                       Prod(Z, T, T)),
               Z=Atom, Y=Epsilon };

    leaves :=
    proc(struct)
        if struct = Y then return 1 fi;
        if struct = Z then return 0 fi;

        return add(leaves(op(q, struct)),
                   q=1..nops(struct));
    end;

    add(y^leaves(t), t in allstructs([T, trees], size=n));
end;

TZY := (1-2*z-sqrt(1-4*z*(1-z+y*z)))/2/z;

GFX := n -> coeftayl(TZY, z=0, n);

GFBINOM :=
n -> add(2^(n+1-2*k)/n*binomial(n,k)*binomial(n-k,k-1)*y^k,
         k=1..floor((n+1)/2));
```

This will produce e.g. for $n=7$ the generating function

$$5\,{y}^{4}+120\,{y}^{3}+240\,{y}^{2}+64\,y$$

which gives the  same result in all three cases,  from the closed form
of $T(z, y)$, by the binomial coefficient formula and by enumeration.

**Remark.** I consulted the linked-to document and the diagram included there would seem to confirm that we have the correct species.